# Integrable in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ from Spin Geometry's Book

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, spin-geometry

For $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $(1+|\xi|)^{-t}$ is integrable in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $t>n$.
Now, for $\xi,\eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$, i need to prove that for every $d\in \mathbb{R}$ exist $s\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

\begin{equation}
\int \int (1 + |\xi|)^{d}(1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{-k}(1 + |\eta|)^{-k} \; d(\xi \times \eta) <\infty
\end{equation}

is integrable in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $k>s$.

I've tried use Peetre's Inequality, where

$(1 + |\xi|)^{d}(1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{-k}(1 + |\eta|)^{-k}$

$= (1 + |\xi - \eta + \eta|)^{d}(1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{-k}(1 + |\eta|)^{-k}$

$\leq (1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{d}(1 + |\eta|)^{|d|}(1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{-k}(1 + |\eta|)^{-k}$

$= (1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{d-k}(1 + |\eta|)^{|d|-k}$

So

\begin{equation}
\int \int (1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{d-k}(1 + |\eta|)^{|d|-k} \; d\eta \; d\xi =
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}= \int (f\star g)(\xi) \; d\xi = ||f\star g||_{1}.
\end{equation}

Where is integrable if $-d+k>n$ and $-|d|+k>n$ ; but iterated integral is not sufficent for say the first integral is finite.

Because this is take from Spin Geomtry's book,page 180. He have

\begin{equation}
\int \int e^{i\langle x,\xi\rangle}\hat{a}(x,\xi-\eta,\xi)\hat{u}(\eta) \; d\eta \; d\xi
\end{equation} and need interchange of integration, and say

\begin{equation}
|\hat{a}(x,\xi-\eta,\xi)||\hat{u}(\eta)|\leq (1 + |\xi|)^{d}(1 + |\xi - \eta|)^{-k}(1 + |\eta|)^{-k}
\end{equation}

so is integrable for $k$ large.